# I updated python 3.6.4 to 3.7.2_2 and all my imported modules stopped working

Tags: python, python-3.7

They are defo installed and working fine before.

for eg. 
from faker import Faker ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'faker' 
 the new symlink is pointing towards python 3.7.2_2. however all site packages still using old python version I think.

getting below error when trying to add those modules again with pip3 install 
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: You need to install those projects for Python 3.7 with pip.

Comment: However, your `pip3` script is configured to run with 3.6, which is no longer installed.

Comment: Work-around: `python3.7 -m pip` will run the right `pip` module.

Comment: worked like a charm.. thanks a ton @MartijnPieters